# Unable to Search for Specific Russian Text in SQL Server ntext Column Using LIKE Operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-like, cyrillic, ntext

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core application that uses Entity Framework Core to interact with a SQL Server database. I have a specific issue where I'm unable to search for Cyrillic text in a column of type `ntext`.

Here's the method I'm using in my repository:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Course>> GetAll(string searchString)
{
    var courses = await _db.Courses
        .Include(c => c.Subcategory) 
        .ToListAsync();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        courses = courses
            .Where(c => c.Subcategory.FullDescription.Contains(searchString))
            .ToList();
    }

    return courses;
}
```

When I pass a Cyrillic string to this method, it returns an empty list even though there are matching records in the database.

I've tried using the `LIKE` operator in SQL Server with a Cyrillic collation, and it works as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM Subcategories
WHERE FullDescription COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI LIKE N'%картинкаТест%';
```

However, I'm not sure how to translate this SQL query into LINQ for use in my repository method.

I've seen this question about the N prefix in T-SQL, but my issue is specifically about how to perform a similar search using Entity Framework Core in C#.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make one little change. When using Unicode string literals (regardless if the column is using an ancient deprecated type, like `ntext`, which you should have stopped using around 2005, for a better and more modern type like `nvarchar(max)`), you need to preface those literals with an `N` (which stands for "national character" or so).

[Repro](https://dbfiddle.uk/sE-nm_v2):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SubCategories
(
  FullDescription ntext COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CS_AS
);

INSERT dbo.SubCategories(FullDescription) VALUES
  (N'no match'), (N'match тест for sure');
```

Your query:

```
SELECT FullDescription
  FROM dbo.SubCategories
  WHERE FullDescription LIKE '%тест%';

-- no results
```

Slight change:

```
SELECT FullDescription
  FROM dbo.SubCategories
  WHERE FullDescription LIKE N'%тест%';
  ---------------------------^

-- now you get a result
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your solution worked perfectly. I was struggling with this issue for a while and your guidance was exactly what I needed. I appreciate the time you took to help me. Thanks again!